# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 32, 10000, 1), found shape=(None, 32, 1000, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow

What is ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 32, 10000, 1), found shape=(None, 32, 1000, 1)?
When I tried to learn model by tensoflow, I get this error. I think that the shape of the data is the same as that used to input the model. Why does they  think this error occure?

```
def EEGNet(nb_classes, Chans = 64, Samples = 128, 
             dropoutRate = 0.5, kernLength = 64, F1 = 8, 
             D = 2, F2 = 16, norm_rate = 0.25, dropoutType = 'Dropout'):
if dropoutType == 'SpatialDropout2D':
        dropoutType = Dropout # SpatialDropout2D
    elif dropoutType == 'Dropout':
        dropoutType = Dropout
    else:
        raise ValueError('dropoutType must be one of SpatialDropout2D '
                         'or Dropout, passed as a string.')
    
    input1   = Input(shape = (Chans, Samples, 1))

    ##################################################################
    block1       = Conv2D(F1, (1, kernLength), padding = 'same',
                                   input_shape = (Chans, Samples, 1),
                                   use_bias = False)(input1)
    block1       = BatchNormalization()(block1)
    block1       = DepthwiseConv2D((Chans, 1), use_bias = False, 
                                   depth_multiplier = D,
                                   depthwise_constraint = max_norm(1.))(block1)
    block1       = BatchNormalization()(block1)
    block1       = Activation('elu')(block1)
    block1       = AveragePooling2D((1, 4))(block1)
    block1       = dropoutType(dropoutRate)(block1)
    
    block2       = SeparableConv2D(F2, (1, 16),
                                   use_bias = False, padding = 'same')(block1)
    block2       = BatchNormalization()(block2)
    block2       = Activation('elu')(block2)
    block2       = AveragePooling2D((1, 8))(block2)
    block2       = dropoutType(dropoutRate)(block2)
        
    flatten      = Flatten(name = 'flatten')(block2)
    
    dense        = Dense(nb_classes, name = 'dense', 
                         kernel_constraint = max_norm(norm_rate))(flatten)
    softmax      = Activation('softmax', name = 'softmax')(dense)
    
    return Model(inputs=input1, outputs=softmax)
l = np.random.rand(9573,32,1000,1)
model = EEGNet(2, Chans = 32, Samples = 10000)
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
      monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0001,
      mode='min', patience=10, verbose=1,
      restore_best_weights=True)
  # Fit model
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9,
                                      beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: `I guess` why do you guess?

Comment: I think that the shape of the data is the same as that used to input the model.
I'm not really used to writing in English.

Comment: Please post your code so that we can help you

Comment: `np.random.rand(9573,32,1000,1)`. This is clearly different from `(None, 32, 10000, 1)`, which you specified by `EEGNet(2, Chans = 32, Samples = 10000)`